# Dir is removed via command in cmd but not with same command in bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to remove a directory, that match some prefix.

I wish that it be possible by invoking some bat file.

Writing `for /D %f in (C:\Windows\Temp\_MEI*) do rmdir /s %f` directly to cmd does delete every folder that match the prefix.

Though, invoking `test.bat` that only has the command line above simply does nothing and i get  "... was unexpected at this time" error.

```
C:\Users\Borat\olympus-skeleton\dist>test.bat
\Windows\Temp\_MEI*) was unexpected at this time.
C:\Users\Borat\olympus-skeleton\dist>for /D \Windows\Temp\_MEI*) do rmdir /s f
C:\Users\Borat\olympus-skeleton\dist>
```

Why is that?

Comment: Use `%%<letter>` in a batchfile.

Comment: Bit new to working with batchfiles. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Instead of `%<letter>` use `%%<letter>`.

Comment: `For /D` will not list all directories, and to remove all of those it does, _(and for which you have sufficient privilege)_, you'd generally use `"%f"` or `"%%f"` in a batch file, _this will account for those which have contain problematic characters_.

Comment: You could have solved your own problem just by reading the first 8 lines of the help file for the `FOR` command.

Comment: I do not think that `FOR /D` will produce quoted paths. But, as a defensive method, I always use `"%~f"` or `"%%~f"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [documentation for `for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for):

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> for {%%|%}<Variable> in (<Set>) do <Command> [<CommandLineOptions>]
> ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> **Parameter**        **Description**
>
> `{%%|%}<Variable>`    Required. Represents a replaceable parameter. Use a single percent sign (%) to carry out the **for** command at the command prompt. Use double percent signs (%%) to carry out the **for** command within a batch file. Variables are case sensitive, and they must be represented with an alphabetical value such as %**A**, %**B**, or %**C**.

Or run `for /?` at the command prompt.

Basically, use `%%f` instead of `%f`.